# getElementById returns null or undefined in Safari

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

Below is a code snippet of some frames I am trying to traverse using the DOM in javascript. I can use `document.getElementById('raiseConfirm').click()` in FF and IE. It will not work in safari. I have tried a multitude of different things to try and get to the anchor with the ID raiseConfirm. It looks as if `document.getElementById()` in this case doesn't find any of the elements in this frame. I have tried `window.document`, `self.document`, `contentWindow`,`contentDocument`, I have tried naming the frame like this, `window.frames['gvdd'].document`, and when I test this, the document is an object and has things in it, but as soon as I try to use the function `getElementById()` on it, it returns `undefined` or `null`.

Can anyone point me to the correct solution?

```
  <form method=​"POST" 
        action=​"somescript.asp?CMD=POST&​TODO=TRUE2" 
        id=​"FORMSV2DISPLAY"
        name=​"FORMSV2DISPLAY">​
    <a id=​"raiseConfirm" href=​"#divConfirm" class=​"nyroModal">HERE IT IS​</a> 
    <div id="divConfirm" style=​"display:​none;​">​…​</div>​
```

Comment: Are you sure the frame has finished loading by the time your script runs (i.e. is your code located in a `load` handler)?

Comment: This does not describe your frame structure, which would be required to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to say this before and it posted weirdly. I was able to fix this problem using JQuery and this is what I did.

```
      $("#raiseConfirm").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery:

```
$('#raiseConfirm')
```

It will surely work on all browsers.
That's the magic of jquery :)

And if you want to attach to the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#raiseConfirm").click(doSomenthing);
});

var doSomenthing = function () {
    /* Something I do here */
}
```

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to `document.getElementById("raiseConfirm")`, so I'm afraid it won't solve the questioner's problem...

Comment: Generally, yes, this is true, but from my experience jquery rocks.

Comment: @Parv, really? Your comment intrigues me, can you elaborate on the differences?

Comment: @Parv, alas, I checked jQuery's source code and there is no workaround for Safari. There is one for Blackberry, and one for IE and Opera (which can return elements by name instead of id), but `getElementById()` is called as-is in all other cases.

Comment: I fixed this myself. This is what I did.

Comment: Exactly equivalent to `document.getElementById()` or not, changing to the jquery selector solved this issue for me. Also, what the heck kind of browser doesn't support such a basic javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById() will not work in safari. Instead you need to use document.all...
Therefore, JQuery comes into picture where it is supported by all browsers. This can be the major difference between Javascript and JQuery where to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in JSFiddle. I couldn't get it to work in Safari without jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/belthasar/Zct4S/

Comment: $("#raiseConfirm").trigger("click");